# Binary tree , Where am I wrong?

Tags: c, pointers, binary-tree

Well this seems to be wrong somewhere ,  maybe memory allocation or pointers(most likely) , what am i doing wrong?

I get the error when i am creating a new node except the first node.The error is not clear.

Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct binary_tree{
    int data;
    struct binary_tree *leftnode;
    struct binary_tree *rightnode;
};

void create_node(struct binary_tree *node , int input)
{
    struct binary_tree *new_node;

    new_node = (struct binary_tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct binary_tree));

    new_node->data      = input;
    new_node->leftnode  = NULL;
    new_node->rightnode = NULL;

    node = new_node;
}

void LNR_traversal(struct binary_tree *node)
{
    while(!(node->leftnode== NULL && node ->rightnode==NULL))
    {
        if(node->leftnode!=NULL)
            LNR_traversal(node->leftnode);
        printf("%d",node->data);
        if(node->rightnode!=NULL)
            LNR_traversal(node->rightnode);
    }

}

int main()
{
    int i;
    int input;

    struct binary_tree *start;
    struct binary_tree *node;

    printf("Data:");
    scanf("%d",&input);
    create_node(start,input);

    //node = start;

    printf("\nDATA:");
    scanf("%d",&input);

    while(input!=-1)
    {
        node = start;

        if(node->leftnode == NULL){
            create_node(node->leftnode,input);
            printf("1");
        }
        else if(node->rightnode == NULL)
            create_node(node->rightnode,input);
        else if(node->leftnode != NULL && node->rightnode!=NULL){
            node = node->leftnode;
            node = node->rightnode;
        }
        printf("\nDATA:");
        scanf("%d",&input);
    }
    node=start;

    LNR_traversal(start);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error? Care to elaborate?

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: Well , i dont seem to know that , I use command line to compile and run C programs! Sorry! :)

Comment: @AmritRajVardhan What is the expected output? What output you are getting? Do you think *elaborating this* has anything to do with you being using command line to run `c` programs?

Comment: Please copy-and-paste the actual and complete output from the compiler and linker, and edit your question to show it. *If* you get build error that is. If you *don't* get build errors, then say so. If you get unexpected results then tell us what you get and what you expected. If you get runtime errors (i.e. crashes) then run in a debugger to locate the crash in your code.
Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Assigning `node->rightnode` to `node` just after assigning `node->leftnode` to `node` seems not what you want.

Comment: This is my question : Is the binary tree sorted or not?

Comment: @rootkea  , well sorry  , i'll try to be more clear next time , noob here , first question in Stack Overflow :), Yes it has a runtime error

Comment: Implementing this program sorted is easier and better

Comment: @MikeCAT Thanks for pointing that out , definitely not what i want!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for the clear explanation of how to use Stack Overflow :) , noob here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On function call in C, arguments are **passed by value**. It means the parameters are **copied** as arguments, so modifying arguments in callee won't affect variables in caller.

Use pointers to modify caller's local variables in callee.

In this case, I think returning allocated node from `create_node()` and having the caller assign the return value is better than using pointers to modify variables.

Answer (score 0):

The problem relies in your `create_node` function.

Code :

```
struct binary_tree *new_node;

new_node = (struct binary_tree *)malloc(sizeof(struct binary_tree));
if ( node ==NULL ) {
    new_node->data      = input;
    new_node->leftnode  = NULL;
    new_node->rightnode = NULL;

    node = new_node;
}
else if (input < node->data) {
    create_node(node->left,input);
}
else {
    create_node(node->right,input);
}
}
```

Actually this is for Binary Sorted Tree

This way when you want to add something to tree just use :

```
create_node(root_node,value);
```

Comment: "Only the root node is allocated."  Yes, if the undefined behavior (using uninitialized auto variable) `node->leftnode == NULL` cause termination of the program.

Comment: This way in your main fucntion just initialize root node and then when you want to add node just call create_node with root as argument